# Using WMS in ArcGIS Viewer for Flex?

Tags: wms, xml, arcgis-flex-viewer

These days i am trying to develop web map using FOSS software. I have a WMS in GeoServer but it does not view in ArcGIS Viewer for Flex.

Can you give me XML code for it?

This is my WMS.

http://localhost:8080/geoserver/sac/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=sac:Luse&styles=&bbox=10.8,1.81,10.57,19.1443&width=512&height=443&srs=EPSG:5235&format=application/openlayers

And is it required crossdomain xml? If yes, how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of a WMS from my config file...

```
<layer label="NWS RADAR" type="wms" autorefresh="66" skipgetcapabilities="true" url="http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cgi-bin/wms/nexrad/n0q.cgi" version="1.1.1" visible="false" visiblelayers="nexrad-n0q-900913" alpha=".5"/>
```

That is a RADAR layer I'm getting from the University of Iowa.  Here is one of my own...

```
<layer label="COUNTY BOUNDARY" wkid="3857" type="wms" skipgetcapabilities="true" url="http://maps.ironcountywi.org:8888/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=C:/Projects/county_webmerc.map" version="1.3.0" visible="true" visiblelayers="COUNTY"/>
```

My layer is in lat-lon, so I added the [wkid="3857"] entry to request the correct projection.

If you have the [skipgetcapabilities="true"] entry, then it doesn't need a cross-site script.

Answer (score 2):

You should check that the spatial references (aka wkid's) of the ESRI Flex Map and the WMS are the same. If not, then check that the WMS supports the spatial reference of the ESRI Flex Map.

I believe that the ESRI Flex Map inherits the spatial reference of the first layer added.  And if your WMS does not support that spatial reference, the WMS layer will never work.

You could try using Firebug/Fiddler/or any other HTTP monitor to see what is getting sent to/from the Viewer.  I believe errors in the WMS Layer class are swallowed silently (i.e. no message displayed to the user).